# How Twitter.com set Apple Touch Icon?

Tags: ios, icon, twitter

Can I use OS X to discover and scrape a web site favorite icon for later reuse? (and I'll deal with any licensing issues if needed - just looking for how to do this for personal use currently)

[Similar to the Favicon, the apple-touch-icon.png is a file used for a web page icon on the Apple iPhone, iPod Touch, and iPad](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/a/appletou.htm).
According to [Specifying a Webpage Icon for Web Clip](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html) there are two ways to set the Apple Touch Icon:
One is to put the apple-touch-icon.png on the root document folder, another is using rel="apple-touch-icon" to add a link element to the webpage. However twitter.com doesn't use any of those methods.

How can I find twitter.com's apple touch icon URL using Safari 8.0 on OS X Yosemite?

Comment: Could you edit this down a bit. What's the practical problem. Are you coding a web site or looking to scrape an existing site? What specific Apple product is in play? iOS 8.3 on an iPad Air 2? Something else? Once this is more clear we can get it to stack overflow if it's a coding issue relating to html or reopen it here if it's on topic.

Comment: I'm use yosemite safari 8.0,it show touch icon in favourite page.I want to scrape an existing site.I want download this icon to use on my website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that's Apple Safari behaviour.It use iPhone UA to get Mobile Webpage,that have Apple Touch Icon in link rel.